# Running PHP file from command line, how do I hide the prompt?

Tags: php, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a Scheduled Task that runs a PHP file every 5 minutes.

It runs

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.4.12\php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\run.php"

That works fine, but every time it runs it opens the Command Prompt window, then once it's done running it closes it.

How do I make it so the Command Prompt window never displays?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make you task run either an user is logged in or not.

there is in option for that in scheduled task

[image]

And with that option you wont see the cmd pop out any more

Edit for solving your question in comment.

Yes you can have the schedule task run every one min with those following option.
[image]7

Re-Edit

Use the following trigger if you want to run the talk every min at computer start 
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solved it! Is there a way to have a Task run every 1 minute instead of every 5?

Comment: This runs the file in the background but it does not appears to be running the required Curl request. Curl is enabled on the WampServer

Comment: I updated my awnser with how to run the task every min, and this problem that you are experiencing is wierd.. since i do all my php script background curl is working great.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, they worked. Will this task automatically start once the computer is restarted as well? Yes it's weird, is there any way I can diagnose why the cURL request isn't working?

Comment: well technically no but something i could think of is the 3 picture il upload in my awnser. Take a look

Comment: Your latest answer solved the problem I was experiencing with running at Startup, but the Curl issue still has me stumped. I've been able to determine that it's not running it at all.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that the PHP command prompt opens (by selecting "Run only when user is logged on"), but make it so the Command Prompt doesn't close once it's run? Or at least output the Command Prompt contents to a text file found in C:\wamp\www\errors.txt